# График некоторого процесса, всплывающий при нажатии кнопки

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Новичок в программировании под Android, при разработке собственного приложения возник вопрос: как лучше всего сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки всплывало диалоговое окно (AlertDialog, например), в котором был бы график некоторого процесса?

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю вам следующий вариант:

1. Создаете отдельный фрагмент, в котором реализуете работу с графиком. График не обязательно реализовывать самому, подберите что-нибудь на https://android-arsenal.com/.
2. В layout-e вы добавляете FrameLayout, в котором будет размещен ваш фрагмент.
3. При нажатии на кнопку, вы делаете видимым FrameLayout и запгружаете свой фрагмент с графиком.
4. Вы можете добавить листенер по клику на этот FrameLayout. При клике - скрывать.